# Copying git history to new Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git

I decided to do a big coding overhaul in one of my Rails apps where it was easier to start again from scratch and then re-add the pieces from my old code one by one until I had most of it reintegrated.  Now I want to basically take what I have now and make it my new app and get rid of the old one, but I want to old git log from that app to be present, and my app changeover to be treated like just another commit (albeit a big one).  Any good way to do this?

I thought of deleting the entire directory structure of the old app except for the .git directory and then copying in the whole directory structure of the new app, adding, and committing, but that seems rather messy.  Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

> I thought of deleting the entire directory structure of the old app except for the .git directory and then copying in the whole directory structure of the new app, adding, and committing, but that seems rather messy. Is there a better way to do it?

That sounds perfect. You'll want a `git add -u` in there as well to catch any deletions.

Comment: Lol well alright then.  I thought there might be a nice git command for this.